# Wix bootstrapper running after restart

Tags: wix, burn

I'm having an issue with my Wix bootstrapper where on some Windows 7 machines it installs successfully and closes with a return code of 0x0 but upon a restart will reload the installer on system startup prompting for uninstall.  I don't see anything wrong in the log file so I really don't know what's going on.  I should mention that every Windows 8 machine I've tested and about half the Windows 7 machines don't have this problem.  If anyone could provide any insight as to why this might be happening or at the very least explain to me how I might be able to see how the installer is being called on the Windows OS (on restart) I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: You could look in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and RunOnce, and the same in HKCU. Possibly the Start menu "Startup" folder. AV apps sometimes interfere in those areas.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately I didn't find anything under either of those registry entries.  What I have found is that for some reason the installer is call "Windows Restart Manager" but I'm still looking into why.

Comment: The Restart Manager is about finding processes that are using files that need to be replaced. It's a helper for FilesInUse-type dialogs.

Comment: @Thermonuclear I know it's an old question, but I facing the same issue. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Yes, although I can't remember the specific details.  I do remember feeling incredibly stupid when I found out what it was and that it was a mistake I made in the bootstrapper and not the fault of Wix toolset.  The best advice I can offer is to carefully look at any place in code where you deal with 'Restart' logic.